# Windows 2019 WMI RPC communication ISystemActivator-RemoteCreateInstace response not reaching source

Tags: tcp, wmi, rpc, tcpdump, dcom

In the project we do WMI queries for monitoring Windows nodes, these queries are failing as the RemoteCreateInstace response not reaching source

WMI Client -
***CentOS 7(aiowmi) (Firewall disabled)***

WMI Server -
***Windows 2019***

In the Windows node necessary services are Running

- *Windows Management Instrumentation*
- *Remote Procedure Call (RPC)*
- *COM+ System Application*
- *DCOM Server Process Launcher*

**Network has got MTU value of 1500**

Followed this article on [Monitoring-Windows-Using-WMI-and-Nagios](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagiosxi/docs/Monitoring-Windows-Using-WMI-and-Nagios-XI.pdf) and made all the changes in the Windows node.

***Wireshark trace from Windows 2019 Server***

[image: Network dump from Windows system]

**Wireshark trace  from CentOS System**

[image: Network dump from CentOS]